Baked/Imported vertices won't take some float data
I have a geometry scatter system set up where I want it to be able to replace the scattered points with baked out/user placed vertices (A collection). I have it working, but the problem is it doesn't work with the LOD system I have, which masks out rings to scatter specific geo (LOD0, LOD1, so on) on the points within the ring based on percentages of a user defined area. This works as intended on points scattered within the geometry node, but as soon as I bake them out and bring them back in, or use manually placed points, the LOD system breaks as the masks don't work on the baked points. In some cases I've realized it's actually using the inverse of the mask input to determine if a point is 0 or 1 (black or white).
The masks work fine on other points, and if I make a noise node and use that on the baked points it works fine (not inverted or anything), so it's something specific to the baked points and the masks I have. I found a work around where I can get the proximity of the baked points/user placed points, which can be applied as a mask on them no problem, and use a maximum math node to combine the LOD mask and the proximity mask, which does make these points 0 or 1 correctly, but then it can't actually use the LOD area as when I try to then remove the proximity mask data from outside of the LOD area, it stops working again and the baked points won't take the data. The baked points are realized and transforms are applied. I have tried converting them to a mesh, converting them to points, etc etc, and nothing of that sort is working. The closest I have gotten is the proximity, but it's an imperfect solution that causes other issues further on. Sorry if this is confusing, it's hard to explain.
